# Get connected to Sharepoint from another website

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list with four different columns (Name, Position, Office, Salary).
In my project, I have to connect to SharePoint website **(Login with specific username and password)**, retrieve all the items in the list and display them in my own website. I read many posts on the internet but nothing useful. I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: are you trying to get SharePoint data in  a site within the same tenant, or some remote website?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider remote website? is there any tutorial available on the internet?

Comment: By remote website i meant, any other website out of the SharePoint tenant that contains the site collection from which you want to retrieve data. if that's the case, please check my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think both of your site is from same domain. Below is the sample code to read items from Sharepoint list using REST API:

```
function retriveListItem()                                                
{
var resultGridHtmlMySubmission=''
  $.ajax (
          {
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<SampleListName(yourlistTitle)>')/items?$select=Title,Name,Position,Office,Salary",
type: "GET",
data: JSON.stringify,
headers:
{
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
"IF-MATCH": "*",
"X-HTTP-Method": null
},
cache: false,
success: function(data)  
{ 
for (vari = 0; i<data.d.results.length; i++)
{
var item = data.d.results[i];
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<tr>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<tdalign="center"   valign="middle"><span title="Sr.No."><b>'+item.Title+'</b></span></td>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<td align="center" valign="middle"><span title="Sr.No."><b>'+item.Name+'</b></span></td>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<td align="center" valign="middle"><span title="Sr.No."><b>'+item.Position+'</b></span></td>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<td align="center" valign="middle"><span title="Sr.No."><b>'+item.Office+'</b></span></td>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='<td align="center" valign="middle"><span title="Sr.No."><b>'+item.Salary+'</b></span></td>';
resultGridHtmlMySubmission+='</tr>';

  }
$("#tbodycontent").html(resultGridHtmlMySubmission);
},
error: function(data)
{
// $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);
}
});
}
```

Similar thread has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336343/retrieve-sharepoint-list-by-js/59340514#59340514)

And if we want to connect SharePoint online site from an external system - we have create **client_id** and **client_secret** instead of username and password.

How to create it - please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395477/upload-files-with-sharepoint-rest-api-and-javascript-from-outside-of-sharepoint/59397333#59397333) thread.

Answer (score 0):

This example REST API getlistitem:

```
var requestUri = "http://sp/sites/test" + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('SharePointList')/items?$select=Name,Position,Office,Slary";
var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success: function (data) 
    {        
       $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
        //Name
        var name = result.Name;
        alert(name);

    });
    },
    error: function ajaxError(response) {
        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @Fox's Answer, for remote websites (out of your SharePoint Tenant),  you might need to obtain an Access Token  and use that in 'Authorization' headers of SharePoint Rest API Calls. Check the following link for details:

> https://medium.com/@anoopt/accessing-sharepoint-data-using-postman-sharepoint-rest-api-76b70630bcbf

This is using POSTMAN to make API calls.